# Batchprogramming, variable initializing, special characters

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I've found an Snippet online and I can understand everything except this line. My problem is, that you can't search for special characters...

```
set params = %*:"=""
```

I know it assign %*:"="" to params, but what does %*:"="" stand for?
In the next line it'll be used to be written in an VBS file

```
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %*~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
```

Comment: This code seems to be stupid :(

Comment: I does exactly what I need, but I want to know why :D

Comment: Where do you think there is a "special" character? I do not see this code doing anything useful. Using `%~s0` would give you an 8.3 name for the script you are currently running.

Comment: I namend special character all non alphanumeric character, don't know how to name it otherwise. I'm not a native English speaker, sorry. %*~s0 is clear for me, but not %*:"=""

Comment: Batch is sometimes very sensitive to spaces. The code that you have posted will assign a string to a variable called `"params "` not `"params"` and you would need to access the variable using`'%params %`Please post the exact original code line by cut-and-paste and tell us what you want the code to do.

Comment: `%*` means all command line arguments passed over to the batch file; the rest is appended literally...

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling I found the page of man who coded this. There is an updated and better code:

https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin